# Force state eg checked="true" for checkbox in Storybook?

Tags: storybook

I have custom styled checkbox. Is there a way in Storybook to make the checkbox checked so that you dont have to click on it to see this state?

Answer (score 0):

This is a work in progress, not fully functioning yet but it does pass props so I am just getting storybook to cooperate.

the storybook-addon-pseudo-states really should have this built in...

I am using a jsx approach but the difference is negligible.

I just started learning Vue and storybook last night, so this is quite new to me, I will post up a fully functional version later.

Checkbox.stories.js

```
export const CheckBoxChecked = Template.bind({});
CheckBoxChecked.args = {
    label: 'Checked',
    checked: true,
};
```

Checkbox.jsx

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { styled, VueEmotion } from '@egoist/vue-emotion';

import './checkbox.css';

Vue.use(VueEmotion);

const Label = styled('label')`
`

const Input = styled('input')`
    opacity: 0;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
`

export default {
    name: 'CheckBox',
    props: {
        label: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        checked: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
render (h) {
        return (
            <Label>
                <Input type="checkbox" checked={this.checked} />
            </Label>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Update, that code does function, and the checkbox state updates to checked based on the story.